# How I can store multilevel comments of user in MySQL dB

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How I can store multilevel comments of user in MySQL dB.

I tried to create a new table comments and in which I have made relationship between users and comments table. My table structure
[ Id primary key int auto_increment, userId int foreign key references users(Id), comments json ].
On first I can easily add and modify comments but when in json object I have to store comment of another comment and comment of that comment. How can I do that?

Comment: Use self-referenced structure `parent_id INT REFERENCES this_table_name (id)`